# replace `\caption[any leng of text]{some text}` with `\caption{some text}` with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I'm not able to catch the error that it is in my reject, and I think I have some missing around, and would be great to have some guidance on this.

I'm try to relate the following content `\caption[any leng of text]{some text}` with `\caption{some text}` by removing the [].

My sed command is the following one

```
sed -i -e 's/caption\(\[[^]\]*\)/caption/g'
```

But I have the wrong result, such as

```
diff --git a/sections/chap_1.tex b/sections/chap_1.tex
index 3eeaa87..5575b76 100644
--- a/sections/chap_1.tex
+++ b/sections/chap_1.tex
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@ un sistema di drenaggio parallelo a quello venoso\cite{BOOK1}.\\
     \begin{center}
     \includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth]{img/ANATOMY2.jpeg}
     \end{center}
-    \caption[Anatomia del sistema linfatico, vasi sanguigni e linfatici]{Anatomia del sistema linfatico, vasi sanguigni e linfatici
+    \caption]{Anatomia del sistema linfatico, vasi sanguigni e linfatici
     \cite{img1}}
```

There is someone that is able to clarify what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/caption\[[^]]*\]/caption/g'
```

Look for string which starts with "caption" followed by "[". Then we zero or multiple symbols which are not "]". Followed by "]".

Replace the whole string with "caption".

Comment: I would change that to `sed -i -e 's/\\caption\[[^]]*\]/\\caption/g'` to only match on `\caption` to be on the safe side.